# I'm on windows os, I'm trying to export the data from mysql workbench to my local file system. But showing an error message like (no disk space)

Tags: python, mysql, windows, mysql-workbench

I've searched many threads online but none of them worked for me. I found solutions for linux but there is no solution related to windows operating system

ERROR: Export data to file: ("Error writing file 'C:\WINDOWS\SERVIC~1\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\MYacdbk0zgsz0sy8wg' (OS errno 28 - No space left on device)", 3)

Comment: Should we assume that you checked that there was in fact space on the C: Drive?

Comment: My first attempt at a fix would be to export the data to another folder NOT within in `C:\WINDOWS` directory

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly, Thanks for your rply. I'm trying to export it to a D:\ Drive.

Comment: Ok, are you saying that  you are adding a D Drive location to the export but it is still giving this error

Comment: Yes Exactly. I tried clearing junk files in temp folder. But the issue was not fixed.Is there any solution or any links to address this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the ddl-dml of some schema, maybe you can do it:

```
1 - On Workbench. Select the Schema.
2 - Database -> Reverse Engineer(Ctrl + r)
3 - Next ... Select the Schema -> execute ... -> the result is a EER diagram.
4 - On EER diagram you do: Database -> Forwading Engineer
5 - Select:
    - Generate INSERT statmentes for tables
    - Disable FK checks for INSERTs
    - Generate DROP SCHEMA
    - Omit schema qualifer in object names
    - include model attached scripts 
6 - Next ...
7 - Copy the script or download it.
```